# Low sound level in Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Tags: 14.04, soundcard, hda-intel

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: 92HD71B7X Analog [92HD71B7X Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: 92HD71B7X Digital [92HD71B7X Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

## 1.

I installed gnome-alsamixer to double check sound settings, all up and volume still low.

## 2.

added

`#/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
options snd-hda-intel model=generic`

and then

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

volume still down